# Does execvp() account for logical operators?

Tags: shell-script, shell, exec

In my class assignment I'm supposed to make my own command shell. In the shell, I am supposed to have it take various command line arguments including logical operators such as `&&` and `||`. I initially assumed that I had to program the shell to behave in the logic such that if the first command is executed, only then the second will proceed if I wanted to make it all work by calling it with execvp(). However, I realized that execp() second parameter probably accounts for the `&&` connector and I could simply just place it as an argument. If I entered `execvp("./shell", "echo hello && mkdir testing")` will it account for the logical operator `&&`?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yeah I did and it worked if I do ```./shell echo hello && mkdir testing``` in the CLI which essentially goes through shell.cpp and inputs it into execvp(). However, when I call shell implementation file from a bash script, it doesn't work.

Comment: It is not clear what you have tried, or what you are trying to do. Please improve question to make it clear.

Comment: @Code4life If you typed that command at an ordinary shell prompt, _that_ shell would run the `mkdir` if your `shell` command exited with a zero exit status.

Comment: so how would I know that my shell failed and it was the original shell interface that executed the command? The shell that I made has perror lines that notifies me if something went wrong with either the fork() or execvp() processes.

Comment: @Code4life If you run _any_ two commands `cmd1 && cmd2` (with `cmd1` being `shell echo hello` in this case), the `&&` would be handled by the calling shell, not by `cmd1` (`shell` in your example).  What you would have to do is to quote the whole argument string, or at least the `&&`.

Comment: How would I make the shell take an argument within quotes?

Answer (score 2):

The `exec*()` calls just start a program and pass the command line arguments to it. The underlying system call doesn't have any knowledge of what the arguments are supposed to mean, that's up to the process that was started.

You could use `exec*()` to run a POSIX-compatible shell, and pass that command line to it, e.g. with `execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", "echo hello && mkdir testing", (char *) NULL)`. The shell would then run that `mkdir` only if the `echo` succeeded.

But since your assignment was to *implement* a shell and the `&&` operator yourself, doing it by calling an external, already existing shell doesn't really seem to be in the spirit of the assignment. You could just use some existing shell to begin with, and not bother writing a single line of C code.

Comment: if you call `execp` as in this answer, it will **crash** or return an error, and nothing of what you say will happen.

Comment: @mosvy, yep. I copied it from the question and apparently didn't think. Of course it was wrong, in several ways. Maybe better now.

Comment: You better write `(void*)0` instead of `NULL`. `NULL` can be defined to simply `0`, in which case an 32bit int will be passed to the `execl` variadic function, which will try to fetch a 64bit pointer and will get garbage instead of a null pointer.

Comment: @mosvy, yep. The Linux man pages have `(char *) NULL`, I think I like that more since the other args are `char *`'s too, and writing `NULL` seems clearer to me than just using `0`.